# Google Map: The marker icon not showing if the button clicked

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps

I wanted to have function when i click the button the marker will be shown in the google map, but first i tried without the click function the marker showing in different location, however when i tried to used the Jquery click function the marker not shown to the place or to the location.

**QUESTION:** How to show all the marks after i click the button.

**PROBLEM:** The problem is the marker not found in the google map after i submit.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="submit_google"  class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-small  red darken-4  " type="submit" name="action" value="Geocode">Find Location
```

**JS:**

```
 $('.city').click(function(){


  var city = $(this).attr('href');

   $('#city_click').val(city);

  jQuery('#submit_google').click();

   var features = [

   {

   position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.459777, -113.406811),
   type: 'info',

   },

  {

     position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.454154, -113.408880),
     type: 'info'
  },

  ];

          // Create markers.
  features.forEach(function(feature) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: feature.position,
  icon: google.maps.marker,
  map: map
  });
});





      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you have an error when using submit buttons. It might try to send you to a new page. Try passing `event` as a parameter to your callbacks and then add: `event.preventDefault();`